# How to scale up real-time kafka consumer without rebalancing latency?

Tags: deployment, apache-kafka, devops

When scaling up\down consumers (adding or removing consumers to group) a rebalance occurs - this make some latency issues in system that makes event to timeout. (saw about 3 sec of producer to consumer latency)
How can I scale up consumers safely without rebalancing process making latency increasing ?

I expect seamless consumers deployments, but the actual behaviour of rebalancing causing timeouts.

Comment: What's the point of adding new consumers if you don't want to rebalance the load?

Comment: I do want to rebalance the load but the kafka rebalancing process takes time and causing timeouts and thats what I want to solve (edited the question to be clearer)

Comment: You really want to try Apache Pulsar.